# shortcut (.LNK) is copied from local network to user pc without his icon

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

I wrote a batch file script in order to copy shortcut from the local network to the user desktop station.
 everything is working perfect **except that the shortcut that is copied to the user desktop is without his icon**.
 I have no experience writing batch files, i will be grateful if someone can advice me how to solve that issue.

that is the script:

```
@echo off
  setlocal
  set alias=Reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP"
  FOR /F "TOKENS=6 DELIMS=\." %%A IN ('%alias%') DO set .NetVer=%%A

 if [%.NetVer] ==[] GOTO noDotNet

if EXIST C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Partner_Projects_System.lnk GOTO ShortCutAllreadyExist

if not exist "\\netapp2\public\all\INTERNET PROJECTS\PMS_Shortcut_noWhite\Partner_Projects_System.lnk" GOTO noPermissionToDir

copy "\\netapp2\public\all\INTERNET PROJECTS\PMS_Shortcut_noWhite\Partner_Projects_System.lnk" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop"

:loop

ping -n 1 -w 3000 1.1.1.1 > nul

IF EXIST C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Partner_Projects_System.lnk (
   GOTO startApp
) ELSE (
   GOTO loop
)

EXIT
pause

:noDotNet
msg "%username%" DOTNET Framework is not installed on your machine please contact partner helpdesk team
EXIT
:noPermissionToDir
msg "%username%" you need to have read and write permission to the path \\netapp2\public\all\INTERNET PROJECTS\ please contact partner helpdesk team
EXIT
:ShortCutAllreadyExist 
msg "%username%" the shortcut is allredy exist on the desktop
EXIT
:startApp
msg "%username%" SHORTCUT TO PROJECT MANAGMENT SOFTWARE WAS CREATED ON YOUR DESKTOP
start C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Partner_Projects_System.lnk
```

Comment: Does the shortcut function properly when run?

Comment: @Steven Vascellaro yes, everything is working as desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shortcut can specify a separate path to a icon that is different from the actual shortcut target. If this path is not valid on the new machine the icon might not display correctly.

You cannot manipulate shortcuts with a batch file but you can with Windows Scripting Host. Try [this script](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_shortcuts.php) to print the shortcut properties.